# Deleting folders/files from completely from history

Tags: git, github

I have a couple big files that I updated a few times through development and they are increasing the size of my git.

I tried using bfg to remove it and followed a tutorial but for some reason it leaves instances of the file in my history.

I am using bfg and here is what I did

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/shultays/bloodworks.git
java -jar ../bfg.jar --delete-folders "steam" bloodworks.git
cd bloodworks.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push
```

And one big file is trailer.mp4 under steam folder. Here is what it looks like in github

https://github.com/shultays/bloodworks/search?q=trailer&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93

as you can see it is still in the history and I can still download the file using this commit

https://github.com/shultays/bloodworks/commit/2c3186173e4cb1381479ef9a4432630cbd16e125

First two commits have 0 changes in them so I assume it worked but in the last two I can still download the file. For example:

https://github.com/shultays/bloodworks/commit/2c3186173e4cb1381479ef9a4432630cbd16e125

Answer (score 0):

You literally cannot delete anything from any historical Git commit.

What `git filter-branch` and the BFG do is build *new* commits—a new history—while omitting the files from those new commits.  You should not expect the files to vanish from the old commits.  You simply stop *using* the old commits, and *pretend* the files are gone.

If you and all other users of the repository no longer use the old commits, and have no names by which the old commits can be found, Git eventually "garbage collects" the unused commits and throws them out of the repository.  At this point, asking for the old commit by hash ID will fail: Git will simply be puzzled, saying, in effect, *I cannot find any object under that hash ID.*

Until Git has actually garbage-collected the commit, though, any request for that commit by that hash ID will get you that commit, which of course brings along all the files that are in it.  Note that as long as you have a *name*—a branch or tag name, or any other external *reference* (as Git calls them—by which Git can find the commit by searching backwards through history, starting from the named object, the old commit will *not* be hauled away as garbage.  For more on the idea of *reachability*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Your:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

command is a way to get your Git to remove extra references and do a garbage collection pass immediately.  You can then use `git show <hash-id>` to see if your own Git hauled the commit out to the trash yet.  But that's just for *your* copy of the repository.

This same logic holds for *every copy of the repository*.  All copies of the repository must have their references updated (usually via `git push --force` or `git fetch` or similar) so that there are no names by which their Gits can find the old commit(s).  Eventually—and for all these *other* copies of the repository, ***you have no control over when***—the other Gits will do their own garbage collection and remove the commits.

GitHub in particular will continue to make the old commit available through the web interface for some amount of time (it's not clear to me how long).